# Add 10 to a $ with switch case

Tags: php, variables, input

First of all, i know i'm very bad at php developement, but i do my best :)
I have 2 select fields, if item Two and option1 are both selected i'd like to add 10 to $price2. So i tried this :

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    items:<br>
    <select name="test[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="three">three</option>
        <option value="four">four</option>
        <option value="five">five</option>
    </select><br>
    options:<br>
    <select name="options" class="quoteFields" tabindex="5" size="1">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose an option</option> 
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
    </select> <br>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
<?php

$test=$_POST['test'];

if ($test){
    foreach ($test as $t){
        echo 'You selected ',$t,'<br />';

        if($t=='one')
            $price1=12;
        if($t=='two')
            $price2=2;
    }
}

if ($_POST['test'] === 'two') {
    switch ($options){

        case "option1":
            $price2 = $price2 + 10;
            break;

    }
}

$total = $price1 + $price2;

echo $total; 
?>
```

But it is not working, anyone can help ?

Comment: You never set `$options` value.

Comment: You're using a comma in stead of the concatenation operator `.`. And you don't really need to concatinate it. Just put the variable in the string: `'You selected $t<br />'`

Comment: @jurgemaister - `echo` can take its parameters as a list as well as a single string

Comment: @andrewsi Indeed. The lovely thing about PHP is the total lack of concistent syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you're looking for is this:

```
if (in_array('two', $_POST['test'], true) && $_POST['options'] === 'option1') {
    // perhaps? $price2 += 10; 
}
```

I'm not sure about the rest of your code, so you'd have to clean that up yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Where comes $options from?

try this:

```
switch ($_POST['options']) {
```